# datetimepicker wont run when include bootstrap.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I try to include datetimepicker to my modal form. My all codes working in another html page. But when I include those code to my own page after clicking to modal button a black blank page opening. 
After spending hours I found out that when I excluded bootsrap.css file it working great. But i need bootsrap styles. 
I try to find and delete modal and btn styles. But it does not change anything. The only solution excluding bootsrap.css.

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/touchTouch.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2708/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/touchTouch.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/packery.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('html').hasClass('desktop')) {
            new WOW().init();
        }
    });
   </script>
<body>
    <div class="item col-sm-3" >
                        <div class="in">
                            <div class="img">
                                <img src="images/arabalar/ekonomi/Dacia-SANDERO.png" width="100%"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="name">
                                Dacia-SANDERO
                            </div>

                         <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
            <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

            <!-- Modal -->
                <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
                <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text">                        </input>
            <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        </div>
</div>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2708/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/index1.js"></script>
```

and the index1.js contain

```
$(function() {
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
         language: 'pt-BR'
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the documentation for this "datetimepicker" library?

Comment: http://s6.dosya.tc/server8/etedk6/site.rar.html